# Call Controllers models and views in codeigniter PATH

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory-structure

I have to use method of a controllers created in codeigniter path: 
[image: modules folder]



In my controller(application/controllers/examplecontroller.php) i have to **load modules controller** that call modules models and modules views.
 
It is possible in codeigniter???

**EDIT:**
I have my controller in application/controllers/hello.php.
Here i have to load a modules that have a controller called for example news.php in folder modules/controllers. This news controller, call a model in modules/news_model.php that load news from my DB. Then, in the controller i have to call a view in modules/views allnews.php that show my news!!
In codeigniter controllers, models and views are in application path! I have to load cotnrollers, models and views in another folder then codeigniter/application path!

Comment: Sorry! Not clear what you asked for!

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do it but its in application folder and its called HMVC Codeigniter assets is basically using for a javascript,images or different files or css files